# Can't create new project with using npx

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, command-line, expo, npx

I can't create new react-native project with using npx. Error permission denied.

If to use sudo, project is created, but in webstorm I couldn't save all changes, So I would open webstorm as admin. My OS Ubuntu.

`npx expo-cli init food`

same as minimal but with TypeScript configuration Uncaught Error { [Error: EACCES: permission denied]

Comment: did you install typescript dependency globally?

Comment: @Kuray-FreakyCoder- I can't remember

Comment: Can you try this command: 
`npm i typescript -g`

Comment: @Kuray-FreakyCoder- I did it.

Comment: Which expo-cli version are you currently using?

Comment: @Kuray-FreakyCoder- How to check expo-cli version?

Comment: `expo-cli --version` to check version

Comment: I've just tried to create a new project with `npx expo-cli init food` command, and it works great. However, before doing that, I upgraded the expo-cli version.

Comment: @Kuray-FreakyCoder- 3.4.1 my expo-cli version

Comment: @Kuray-FreakyCoder- How I said I can create with sudo. But in webstorm I couldn't edit my code.